# Docker error with pip version while building new image

Tags: python, docker, pip

I have an issue with the build of a new image using python on Docker (RHEL7).

I used this code to create the image with a Dockerfile builder:

```
docker build -t navitia-builder .
```

And the following error appear:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-uSw6UQ/cffi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-FjGJow-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-uSw6UQ/cffi
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

But I already installed pip version 8.1.2 and installed requirements for my image:

```
docker-compose==1.2.0  
docker-py==1.1.0  
pytest==2.7.1  
requests==2.5.3 
fabric==1.10.2  
jinja2==2.8 
nose==1.3.7
```

I also upgraded the setuptools.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.3

WORKDIR /usr/local/navitia

RUN apk add --update \
    alpine-sdk \
    libffi-dev
    python \
    python-dev \
    py-pip \
    docker \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
# Install openrc - see: https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/42
RUN apk update && apk add openrc &&\
# Tell openrc its running inside a container, till now that has meant LXC
    sed -i 's/#rc_sys=""/rc_sys="lxc"/g' /etc/rc.conf &&\
# Tell openrc loopback and net are already there, since docker handles the networking
    echo 'rc_provide="loopback net"' >> /etc/rc.conf &&\
# no need for loggers
    sed -i 's/^#\(rc_logger="YES"\)$/\1/' /etc/rc.conf &&\
# can't get ttys unless you run the container in privileged mode
    sed -i '/tty/d' /etc/inittab &&\
# can't set hostname since docker sets it
    sed -i 's/hostname $opts/# hostname $opts/g' /etc/init.d/hostname &&\
# can't mount tmpfs since not privileged
    sed -i 's/mount -t tmpfs/# mount -t tmpfs/g' /lib/rc/sh/init.sh &&\
# can't do cgroups
    sed -i 's/cgroup_add_service /# cgroup_add_service /g' /lib/rc/sh/openrc-run.sh

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/local/navitia/docker_navitia/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /usr/local/navitia/docker_navitia/requirements.txt

RUN git clone https://github.com/CanalTP/fabric_navitia.git /usr/local/navitia/fabric_navitia
RUN pip install -r /usr/local/navitia/fabric_navitia/requirements.txt

ENV PYTHONPATH /usr/local/navitia:/usr/local/navitia/docker_navitia:/usr/local/navitia/fabric_navitia:/usr/bin/python

# RUN echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/sbin/init && service docker start' > /usr/local/navitia/entrypoint.sh && chmod +x /usr/local/navitia/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/local/navitia/docker_navitia

WORKDIR /usr/local/navitia/docker_navitia

ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/init"]
```

And now I need you because I have no more ideas.

Comment: Pip being out of date is not sufficient to cause a fatal error.  Show us more of the output from the `docker build` command, and ideally also show us your Dockerfile.

Comment: yes, and make sure you apply all these changes into Dockerfile, not on the host. eg. if you have pip 8.1.2 on host doesn't mean you have pip in the container too.